# Reformatting json using python

Tags: python, json, javascript-objects

I'm receiving json file like below :

```
[
    {
        "from":"BUS_TYPE_CODE",
        "to":"BUS_TYPE_CODE"
    }
    ,
    {
        "from":"RECORD_TYPE_IDENTIFIER",
        "to":"RECORD_TYPE_IDENTIFIER"
    }
]
```

But I want to reformat it like below before sending to external teams for processing, Any help would be highly appreciated!!.

```
[
    {
        "from":["BUS_TYPE_CODE"],
        "to":["BUS_TYPE_CODE"]
    }
    ,
    {
        "from":["RECORD_TYPE_IDENTIFIER"],
        "to":["RECORD_TYPE_IDENTIFIER"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is Converting `"BUS_TYPE_CODE"` to `["BUS_TYPE_CODE"]` challenging? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I receive huge json file like this everyday I need a quicker way to change the value of this json and send it. Looking for a quicker and easier way to do this and moreover values are always dynamic.

Comment: I did not say to do it manually. Parse the file using the  `json` module and then access `parsed[i]["from"]` and convert it to a list.

Comment: I tried something like this, but didn't give me output i expect. 
with open(output, 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    json_data[0]['from'] = list(json_data[0]['from'])
    print(json_data[0])

{'from': ['B', 'U', 'S', '_', 'T', 'Y', 'P', 'E', '_', 'C', 'O', 'D', 'E'], 'to': 'BUS_TYPE_CODE'}

Comment: Don't use `list("string")` instead use `["string"]` in your case `a[0]["from"] = [ a[0]["from"]]`

Comment: Thank you so much sir. ble answer below works out perfectly for me. appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

with open('nameoffile.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
for dictionary in data:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[key]=[value]
```

Than just print it

```
print(data)
```

Or write in another file:

```
f = open("newfile.json", "w")
f.write(json.dumps(data))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ble, this works perfectly for my usecase. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution (`json_obj` is your input JSON object):

```
new_json_obj = [{k: [v] for k, v in d.items()} for d in json_obj]
```